# C programming - hexadecimal or decimal convention

Tags: c, hex

My question is pretty simple. I am newbie in microcontrollers world and trying to understand usage of haxadecimal or decimal naming conventions. I saw much C code and first part of programmers uses decimal naming convention:

```
#define TEST_BUTTON_PORT  1
#define TEST_BUTTON_BIT   19
```

the second part uses hexadecimal way:

```
#define IOCON_FUNC0  0x0                 
#define IOCON_FUNC1  0x1
```

Is any important reason for different conventions? Is just a programmer choice?

Comment: hexadecimal (and binary) is often easier to read when working with bitwise operations (or bitmasks)

Comment: Try to convert a decimal value to binary. Then try the same thing for a hexadecimal value. Now which one is easier?

Comment: Use whatever is convenient in each case.

Comment: When it comes to bits and bit-masks hexadecimal is usually used, as it's easier to "see" what bit or bits are set. Or for a single bit in a mask then using shift (like e.g. `1 << 19`).

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of hex is to ease the use of binary numbers, since binary is very hard for humans to read. Some examples when hexadecimal is used:

- Describing binary numbers and binary representations.
- Dealing with hardware addresses.
- Doing bit-wise arithmetic.
- Declaring bit masks/bit fields.
- Dealing with any form of raw data, such as memory dumps, machine code or data protocols.

An exception to this is, oddly, when specifying the number of bits to shift. This is almost always done in decimal notation. If you wish to set bit 19 you would usually do it by writing:

```
PORT |= 1 << 19;
```

This assuming bits are enumerated from 0 to *n*.

I suppose this is because decimal format is more convenient when enumerating things, such as bit/pin numbers. (And manufacturers of MCUs etc usually enumerate pins with decimal notation.)